# Google Apps Script - check if a value is in one of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

I want to sort a few rows by a column "Department". To do this I want to create an array with the names of the members of each department and then through a loop I would like to check the Names column. If the surname is included in the "departmentOne" array, then in the line next to it (Department column) the inscription "Department One" will appear, if not, the next array - departmentTwo is checked and so on until each surname is assigned to a right department.

First of all - Im totally newbie so sorry for mistakes because sometimes I don't know exactly what I'm doing.

```
function setDepartment() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  

  var departmentOne = ['SURNAME1','SURNAME2','SURNAME3'];
  var departmentTwo = ['SURNAME4','SURNAME5','SURNAME6'];
  
  var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

for (var i=4;i<=25;i++){


if(workingCell = Array.isArray(departmentOne)){
    activeSheet.getRange(i,1).setValue("Department One");
    
  }
 
else if(workingCell = Array.isArray(departmentTwo)){
    activeSheet.getRange(i,1).setValue("Department Two");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `if (departmentOne.includes(workingCell)) { // workingCell is in dept 1! }`

Comment: Hi. Would you please provide some sample data (to go with your script) and an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, it works! The amount of knowledge available in internet can be overwhelming :D

Comment: if(~depatmentOne.indexOf(workingCell) ) {workingCell is in dept1} [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setDepartment() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var d1 = ['SURNAME1', 'SURNAME2', 'SURNAME3'];
  var d2 = ['SURNAME4', 'SURNAME5', 'SURNAME6'];
  const vs = sh.getRange(4, 2, 22).getValues().flat();
  let o = vs.map((e, i) => {
    if (~d1.indexOf(e)) {
      return ["Department One"];
    } else if (~d2.indexOf(e)) {
      return ["Department Two"];
    } else {
      return [];
    }  
  });
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```